# Does table1 UNION ALL table2 guarantee output order table1, table2?

Tags: sql, database, sql-order-by, union, union-all

```
SELECT a FROM b
UNION ALL 
SELECT a FROM c
UNION ALL 
SELECT a FROM d
```

Does UNION ALL guarantee to print out records from tables b, c, d in that order? I.e., no records from c before any from b. This question is not for a specific DBMS.

Comment: `ORDER BY` is the *only* way to guarantee the order of results in a query in standard SQL.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server UNION - What is the default ORDER BY Behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421049/sql-server-union-what-is-the-default-order-by-behaviour)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No order by, no order guarantee whatsoever - that's for every database.

And for standard SQL, an ORDER BY is applied to the results from all the unioned queries.

Answer (score 1):

To be sure in order use

```
Select 1 as TableNo,* from a
union all 
select 2 as TableNo,* from b
union all
select 3 as TableNO,* from c
order by TableNo, [desired column]
```