# EF 5 union not working as expected

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

I have a linq query involving the following 3 entities:

```
public class LandPoint
{
    ...
    public OlsonTimeZone TimeZone { get; set; }
}

public class OlsonTimeZone : TimeZone
{
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<WindowsTimeZone> Windows { get; set; }
}

public class WindowsTimeZone : TimeZone
{
    ...
    public virtual ICollection<OlsonTimeZone> Olson { get; set; }
}
```

So a LandPoint has an OlsonTimeZone which has zero or more WindowsTimeZones.

What I am trying to do is get the WindowsTimeZone name (prefixed by 'Windows:') if the OlsonTimeZone has any WindowsTimeZones or the OlsonTimeZone name (prefixed by 'Olson:') as a fall back along with information about the point itself.

What I have written is:

```
 return db.LandPoints.Where(x => x.GeoNameID == ID).Take(1).Select(x => new LandPoint
        {
            TimeZone = x.TimeZone
                            .Windows.Select(t => "Windows:" + x.Name)
                            .Union(new[] { "Olson:" + x.TimeZone.Name })
                            .FirstOrDefault()
        }).First();
```

Which should in theory do what I want. Except that for a given point that I tested it with (which I know has a WindowsTimeZone associated with) it returned the OlsonTimeZone instead of the WindowsTimeZone.
If for the same ID i write the following:

```
return db.LandPoints.Where(x => x.GeoNameID == ID).Take(1).Select(x => new LandPoint
        {
            TimeZone = x.TimeZone
                            .Windows.Select(t => "Windows:" + x.Name)
                            .FirstOrDefault()
        }).First();
```

I get the WindowsTimeZone.

I am sure I could rewrite it using a CASE statement but I felt this was more elegant. Since the way its behaving is somewhat counter intuitive and understanding why it is doing what it does would help me get a better feeling of how linq queries translate to sql I decided to post a question here.

**So why is it doing what it does? Is there some addition to the code above that would make it work (maintaining the UNION statement)?**

Thanks in advance
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because union doesn't guarantee ordering. You cannot put any special expectations based on order of items without ordering them. But your code should fire `NotSupportedException` because this is not allowed: `db.LandPoints.Select(x => new LandPoint ...`

If you have `LandPoint` entity mapped by entity framework you cannot project to this type in Linq-to-entities.

Comment: It actually does not fire NotSupportedException. I based my query on my understanding of sql union where indeed the top query results are followed by the bottom query results. I guess I learned something though.

Comment: What you saw was just coincidence. Union in SQL does not guarantee ordering.

Comment: It seems you are right again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473419/does-table1-union-all-table2-guarantee-output-order-table1-table2