# Select query with specific pattern, show specific record at 1st place

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM station
```

Output:

```
id | stationname | total
-------------------------
 1 | Khar        | 5
 2 | SantaCruz   | 3
 3 | Sion        | 2
 4 | VT          | 1
 5 | newFort     | 3
 6 | Bandra      | 2
 7 | Worli       | 1
 8 | Sanpada     | 3
 9 | Joe         | 2
10 | Sally       | 1
11 | Elphiston   | 2
12 | Currey Road | 1
```

Is it possible to display all the record but with a condition that will display particular record at 1st position and below then display rest all records

E.g. my `where` condition is

```
where id=10
```

Desired output:

```
id | stationname | total
-------------------------
10 | Sally       | 1
 1 | Khar        | 5
 2 | SantaCruz   | 3
 3 | Sion        | 2
 4 | VT          | 1
 5 | newFort     | 3
 6 | Bandra      | 2
 7 | Worli       | 1
 8 | Sanpada     | 3
 9 | Joe         | 2
11 | Elphiston   | 2
12 | Currey Road | 1
```

Any idea, hint will be appreciated

Comment: Why on earth you want result like this?

Comment: You could try order by column = 10. Havent tried it my self.

Comment: @hims056: thanks for reply, well its a requirement in my project and even am not sure who to achive this, so i asked here

Comment: @s093294:thnks for rpely , order by work for asec or desc, here i need different requirement

Comment: I will check when at a pc, but you saying you cant order by a column? And if you can order by a column- i would assume sql could handle a expression in the order clause. Ect order by column1+ column2 asec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can union two different query using `UNION ALL` like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Station WHERE ID=10
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Station WHERE ID<>10
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b0f65/13)

---

**Update** (related to [returned order is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540406/select-query-with-specific-pattern-show-specific-record-at-1st-place/13540470#comment18543042_13540470))

If you see the execution plan of both queries (using `UNION` and `UNION ALL`), the query using `UNION` will sort the result while the query using `UNION ALL` will **not** sort the result. see execution plan of both queries [in this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b0f65/15).

Execution Plan using `UNION` query:

[image]

Execution Plan using `UNION ALL` query:

[image]

I found this from [SQL SERVER – Introduction and Example of UNION and UNION ALL](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/10/15/sql-server-introduction-and-example-of-union-and-union-all/)

Comment: Thank you, +1 for using sql fiddle

Comment: A note of warning: This *might* fail because the [returned order is undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421049/sql-server-union-what-is-the-default-order-by-behaviour).

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers - Look at [OP's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/634196/1369235) `UNION ALL` will stop sorting.

Comment: @hims056 - I missed that answer but OP neglects to give any reference. My gut feeling tells me you are right though. +1 on your answer until proven wrong :)

Comment: thanks to both of you, both query solved my problem, and i am using union all

Comment: @hims056 - the +1 stands as your answer is correct for OP's problem but bypassers might want to read the conversation and warnings expressed in [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13540545/52598).

Answer (score 3):

Using a `UNION ALL` could work in the case presented by OP but comes with some pitfalls that might lead to unexpected results when used indiscriminately.

A searched sort order alleviates these problems, provided that an `id` can be choosen to be guaranteed the first in the list *(0 in this example)*

```
SELECT * 
FROM   Station 
ORDER BY
       CASE WHEN id = 10 THEN 0 ELSE id END
```

[See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b0f65/14) *(cudo's to hims056 for setting it up)*

Comment: @satindersingh - Thank you. I might have added that the `THEN` clause should contain the lowest possible `id` value but I assume that speaks for itself.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers - Your solution is better.

Comment: @hims056 - it might. Time will tell ;)

Comment: In free time will definetly do rearch on this which one is better, soon you get to know :)

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers - In the execution plan of both queries (using `UNION` and `UNION ALL`), query using `UNION` will sort the result while query using `UNION ALL` will not sort the result. see execution plan of both queries [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b0f65/15). I found it from [this article](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/10/15/sql-server-introduction-and-example-of-union-and-union-all/)

Comment: @hims056 - I finally taken the time to test one and another. For this particular case it works but to prove a point *(yes I **am** that evil)*, I have altered the statements a bit and added a clustered index **without altering the insert order**. You will notice that the results are now returned not on insert order but on clustered index order. All in all, you can trust on the UNION ALL behaving the way you expect but you have to keep in mind all those little things that might throw off your results. [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/dc0ce/1)

Comment: This is the correct answer. The Union method may not produce the expected sort all the time.