# how to get some records in first row in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have q query like this:

```
 Select  WarehouseCode  from [tbl_VW_Epicor_Warehse]
```

my output looks like this

```
WarehouseCode
Main
Mfg
SP
W01
W02
W03
W04
W05
```

But sometimes I want to get W04 as the first record, sometimes I want to get W01 as the first record .

How I can write a query to get some records in first row??
Any help is appreciated

Comment: You can use CASE statement with ORDER BY Clause to achieve same.

Comment: can you able to write code for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try and select the row with the code you want to appear first by specifying a where condition to select that row alone then you can union all another select with all other rows that doesn't have this name

as follows

> ```
> SELECT WarehouseCode FROM Table WHERE WarehouseCode ='W04'
> UNION ALL 
> SELECT WarehouseCode FROM Table WHERE WarehouseCode <>'W04'
> ```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15766359/does-union-all-guarantee-the-order-of-the-result-set

Comment: i think this will work. you can pass first item as a parameter.

Comment: Dear @jasjas but its not guarantee it will work always, most of the time YES it will work

Comment: dear @NeerajPrasadSharma I'm curious about the cases when this might not work, could you please elaborate

Comment: Dear @MahaKhairy please see my EDITED answer please

Answer (score 1):

Use a parameter to choose the top row, which can be passed to your query as required, and sort by a column calculated on whether the value matches the parameter; something like the `ORDER BY` clause in the following:

```
DECLARE @Warehouses TABLE (Id INT NOT NULL, Label VARCHAR(3))

INSERT @Warehouses VALUES
 (1,'W01')
,(2,'W02')
,(3,'W03')

DECLARE @TopRow VARCHAR(3) = 'W02'

SELECT *
FROM @Warehouses
ORDER BY CASE Label WHEN @TopRow THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @ankit bajpai

You are looking for **Custom sorting** that is achieve by CASE with ORDER BY statement

Whenever  you want WAo4 on top you can use

```
 ORDER BY Case When col = 'W04'  THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
```

> Example below:

```
Select col from 
(
select 'Main' col  union ALL
select  'Mfg' union ALL
select  'SP' union ALL
select  'W01' union ALL
select  'W02' union ALL
select  'W03' union ALL
select  'W04' union ALL
select  'W05' 
) randomtable 

ORDER BY Case When col = 'W04'  THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
```

**EDIT: AFTER MARKED AS ANSWER**

IN support of @Maha Khairy because that IS MARKED AS ANSWER and the only answer which is DIFFRENT
rest all are pushing OP to use "ORDER by with case statements"

> let`s use UNION ALL APPROCH

```
create table #testtable (somedata  varchar(10))

insert into #testtable

Select col from 
(
 select  'W05'  col union ALL
select 'Main'   union ALL
select  'Mfg' union ALL
select  'SP' union ALL
select  'W01' union ALL
select  'W02' union ALL
select  'W03' union ALL
select  'W04'

) randomtable 


Select * From #testtable where somedata = 'W04'
Union ALL
Select * From #testtable where somedata <> 'W04'
```

The result set is rendering data to the grid as requested the OP

idia is to get first all rows where equal to 'W04' is and then 
not equal to 'W04' and then concatinate the result. so that rows  'W04'
will always be on the top because its used in the query first, fair enough.

, but that is not the only point to use (custom sorting/sorting) in that fasion there is one another
and a major one that is PERFORMANCE
yes 
"case with order by" will never able to take advantages of KEY but Union ALL will be, to explore it more buld the test table
and check the diffrence

```
CREATE TABLE  #Orders
(  
    OrderID    integer  NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    CustID     integer  NOT NULL,
    StoreID    integer  NOT NULL,
    Amount     float    NOT NULL,

    makesrowfat nchar(4000)
);
GO
-- Sample data
WITH  
    Cte0 AS (SELECT 1 AS C UNION ALL SELECT 1), --2 rows  
    Cte1 AS (SELECT 1 AS C FROM Cte0 AS A, Cte0 AS B),--4 rows  
    Cte2 AS (SELECT 1 AS C FROM Cte1 AS A ,Cte1 AS B),--16 rows 
    Cte3 AS (SELECT 1 AS C FROM Cte2 AS A ,Cte2 AS B),--256 rows 
    Cte4 AS (SELECT 1 AS C FROM Cte3 AS A ,Cte3 AS B),--65536 rows 
    Cte5 AS (SELECT 1 AS C FROM Cte4 AS A ,Cte2 AS B),--1048576 rows 
    FinalCte AS (SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY C) AS Number FROM   Cte5)


INSERT  #Orders 
    (CustID, StoreID, Amount)
SELECT 
    CustID  = Number / 10,
    StoreID = Number % 4,
    Amount  = 1000 * RAND(Number)
FROM FinalCte
WHERE 
    Number <= 1000000;
GO
```

*lets now do the same for custid "93190"*

```
Create NONclustered Index IX_CustID_Orders ON #Orders (CustID)
INCLUDE (OrderID ,StoreID, Amount ,makesrowfat    )
```

> WARM CHACHE RESULTS

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON

 DECLARE @OrderID     integer 
 DECLARE @CustID      integer 
 DECLARE @StoreID     integer 
 DECLARE @Amount      float   
 DECLARE @makesrowfat nchar(4000)


Select  @OrderID    =OrderID ,   
        @CustID     =CustID    , 
        @StoreID    =StoreID    ,
        @Amount     =Amount     ,
        @makesrowfat=makesrowfat

        FROM
(
Select * From  #Orders where custid =93190
Union ALL
Select * From  #Orders where custid <>93190
)TLB
```

**

> --elapsed time =2571 ms.

**

```
 DECLARE @OrderID     integer 
 DECLARE @CustID      integer 
 DECLARE @StoreID     integer 
 DECLARE @Amount      float   
 DECLARE @makesrowfat nchar(4000)

 Select  @OrderID    =OrderID ,   
        @CustID     =CustID    , 
        @StoreID    =StoreID    ,
        @Amount     =Amount     ,
        @makesrowfat=makesrowfat

        From  #Orders

 ORDER BY Case When custid = 93190  THEN 1 ELSE 2 END
```

> elapsed time = 70616 ms

**

> UNION ALL performance       2571 ms.   ORDER BY CASE performance 
>   70616 ms

**

UNION ALL is a clear winner ORDER BY IS not ever nearby in performance

**BUT** we forgot that SQL is declarative language,
  we have no direct control over how data has fetch by the sql, there is a software code ( that changes with the releases)
  IN between 
  user and sql server database engine, which is SQL SERVER OPTIMIZER that  is coded to get the data set
  as specified by the USER and  its has  responsibility to get the data with  least amount of resources. so there are chances 
  that you wont get ALWAYS the result in order until you specify ORDER BY

some other references:

**@Damien_The_Unbeliever**
  [Why would anyone offer an ordering guarantee except when an ORDER BY clause is included? -
   there's an obvious opportunity for parallelism (if sufficient resources are available) to compute each result set in parallel and serve each result row
    (from the parallel queries) to the client in whatever order each individual result row becomes available. –](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15766359/does-union-all-guarantee-the-order-of-the-result-set)

**Conor Cunningham:**
  [If you need order in your query results, put in an ORDER BY.  It's that simple.  Anything else is like riding in a car without a seatbelt.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/conor_cunningham_msft/archive/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by.aspx)

ALL COMMENTS AND EDIT ARE WELCOME

Answer (score 0):

May be you don't need to store this list in table? And you want something like this?

```
SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('WarehouseCode'),
                        ('Main'),
                        ('Mfg'),
                        ('SP'),
                        ('W01'),
                        ('W02'),
                        ('W03'),
                        ('W04'),
                        ('W05')) as v(s)
```

Here you can change order manually as you want.