# it is possible to concatenate one result set onto another in a single query?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table of Verticals which have names, except one of them is called 'Other'.  My task is to return a list of all Verticals, sorted in alpha order, except with 'Other' at the end.  I have done it with two queries, like this:

```
String sqlMost = "SELECT * from core.verticals WHERE name != 'Other' order by name";
String sqlOther = "SELECT * from core.verticals WHERE name = 'Other'";
```

and then appended the second result in my code.  Is there a way to do this in a single query, without modifying the table?  I tried using UNION

```
(select * from core.verticals where name != 'Other' order by name)
UNION (select * from core.verticals where name = 'Other');
```

but the result was not ordered at all.  I don't think the second query is going to hurt my execution time all that much, but I'm kind of curious if nothing else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UNION ALL` is the usual way to request a simple concatenation; without `ALL` an implicit `DISTINCT` is applied to the combined results, which often causes a sort.  However, `UNION ALL` [isn't required to preserve the order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15766414/55637) of the individual sub-results as a simple concatenation would; you'd need to `ORDER` the overall `UNION ALL` expression to lock down the order.

Another option would be to compute an integer order-override column like `CASE WHEN name = 'Other' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END`, and `ORDER BY` that column followed by name, avoiding the `UNION` entirely.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!  I had thought of your second answer (though not the CASE to auto-set the value), but wondered if it could be done with the existing table definition.  Edited my original question accordingly.  re: your first suggestion, wouldn't ordering the UNION ALL just put the 'Other' back into alpha order?  I just tried UNION ALL without the overall ordering and it did what I wanted, but if it's not guaranteed then I can't count on it.

Comment: You'd need the synthetic column to guarantee the special ordering you're looking for.  You can do that in the query without modifying the base table, though.