# ORACLE SQL How to implement a UNION clause but maintain the order of each SELECT

Tags: sql, oracle, union

Using a `UNION` clause in two `SELECT` statements how can I guarantee the order of execution?
For example:

```
SELECT a.poclcdde, a.poclnpol, a.poclcdcl
  FROM dtpocl a
 WHERE     a.poclcdcl IN (216450,
                          562223,
                          250056,
                          202153,
                          8078)
       AND POCLCDCE = 0
       AND POCLTPSG = '01'
UNION
SELECT a.poclcdde, a.poclnpol, a.poclcdcl
  FROM dtpocl a
 WHERE     a.poclcdcl IN (216450,
                          562223,
                          250056,
                          202153,
                          8078)
       AND POCLTPSG = '02'

 POCLCDDE   POCLNPOL   POCLCDCL
---------- ---------- ----------
       100    1000001     202153
       100    5001021     216450
       100    9000386       8078
       100    9900633     250056
       100    9900634     250056
       100    9901720     562223
       100    9901763     562223
       200    1000001     202153
       200    5001021     216450
```

In this case, How can I guarantee that the first records are from query1 and the rest are from query2.
I could use `poclcdcl` column (or a virtual column) and then order by that, but in this case I need to get `DISTINCT` rows.

```
  SELECT *
    FROM (SELECT a.poclcdde,
                 a.poclnpol,
                 a.poclcdcl,
                 1 AS TYPE
            FROM dtpocl a
           WHERE     a.poclcdcl IN (216450,
                                    562223,
                                    250056,
                                    202153,
                                    8078)
                 AND POCLCDCE = 0
                 AND POCLTPSG = '01'
          UNION
          SELECT a.poclcdde,
                 a.poclnpol,
                 a.poclcdcl,
                 2 AS TYPE
            FROM dtpocl a
           WHERE     a.poclcdcl IN (216450,
                                    562223,
                                    250056,
                                    202153,
                                    8078)
                 AND POCLTPSG = '02')
ORDER BY TYPE


  POCLCDDE   POCLNPOL   POCLCDCL       TYPE
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
       200    1000001     202153          1
       100    1000001     202153          1
       100    9000386       8078          1
       100    9900634     250056          2
       100    9901720     562223          2
       100    9901763     562223          2
       200    5001021     216450          2
       100    9000386       8078          2
       100    5001021     216450          2
       100    9900633     250056          2
```

I need this to interact each row by that order: the first query prevails.
Thanks

Comment: You can't, since UNION removes duplicates.

Comment: Ok... and without using UNION? Is there any way?

Comment: You can do UNION ALL. Add `1` to first select, and `2` to second. Order by that column.

Comment: `UNION ALL` don't remove duplicates. That is my second approach using `UNION`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `union all` with the `type` "virtual" column to get the right order, and use a filter on the returned value of the `row_number` analytic function to remove the duplicates while prioritizing the first query's rows:

```
with cte as (
          SELECT a.poclcdde,
                 a.poclnpol,
                 a.poclcdcl,
                 1 AS TYPE
            FROM dtpocl a
           WHERE     a.poclcdcl IN (216450,
                                    562223,
                                    250056,
                                    202153,
                                    8078)
                 AND POCLCDCE = 0
                 AND POCLTPSG = '01'
          UNION ALL
          SELECT a.poclcdde,
                 a.poclnpol,
                 a.poclcdcl,
                 2 AS TYPE
            FROM dtpocl a
           WHERE     a.poclcdcl IN (216450,
                                    562223,
                                    250056,
                                    202153,
                                    8078)
                 AND POCLTPSG = '02'
)
select poclcdde, poclnpol, poclcdcl
  from (select t.*,
               row_number() over (
                 partition by t.poclcdde, t.poclnpol, t.poclcdcl
                     order by t.type) as rn
          from cte t)
 where rn = 1
 order by type
```

Comment: Thanks @sstan. I get a "virtual" row order. But how can I confirm this? Doesn't `UNION ALL` return a random row order?

Comment: Yes, but that's why I have the `ORDER BY type` clause in the outer query, to ensure that rows from the 1st query always appear *before* rows from the 2nd query.  That is what you were looking for, right?

Answer (score 3):

You could do this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT a.poclcdde,
               a.poclnpol,
               a.poclcdcl,
               1 AS TYPE
          FROM dtpocl a
         WHERE     a.poclcdcl IN (216450,
                                  562223,
                                  250056,
                                  202153,
                                  8078)
               AND POCLCDCE = 0
               AND POCLTPSG = '01'
        UNION
        SELECT a.poclcdde,
               a.poclnpol,
               a.poclcdcl,
               2 AS TYPE
          FROM dtpocl a
         WHERE     a.poclcdcl IN (216450,
                                  562223,
                                  250056,
                                  202153,
                                  8078)
               AND POCLTPSG = '02'
               AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                                 FROM dtpocl a
                                WHERE     a.poclcdcl IN (216450,
                                                         562223,
                                                         250056,
                                                         202153,
                                                         8078)
                                  AND POCLCDCE = 0
                                  AND POCLTPSG = '01')
               )
ORDER BY TYPE
```

Comment: Thanks @Tony. It works and it was one of the other solution that I've remember. But can `UNION` guaranteed to preserve the order? As this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15766359/does-union-all-guarantee-the-order-of-the-result-set - , I don't think so.

Comment: No, you need to specify whatever order you need in the ORDER BY clause.  That goes for any query whatsoever!

Answer (score 3):

You are selecting the same columns from the same table, so you don't need two queries, but just one with an appropriate `WHERE` clause. The `ORDER BY` clause is simple in your case; in more complicated cases you'd use `CASE WHEN` expressions in `ORDER BY`.

```
select poclcdde, poclnpol, poclcdcl
from dtpocl
where poclcdcl in (216450, 562223, 250056, 202153, 8078)
and
(
  (pocltpsg = '01' and poclcdce = 0)
  or
   pocltpsg = '02'
)
order by pocltpsg;
```

---

**UPDATE:** You say that you get duplicates, but once you use `DISTINCT`, you are not allowed to sort by `pocltpsg`. This is true, as for one combination of `poclcdde, poclnpol, poclcdcl` you may have records with both `pocltpsg` = '01' and '02'. So you would have to aggregate by `poclcdde, poclnpol, poclcdcl` and decide whether to sort by `min(pocltpsg)` or `max(pocltpsg)` (or any other aggregate for that matter).

```
select poclcdde, poclnpol, poclcdcl
from dtpocl
where poclcdcl in (216450, 562223, 250056, 202153, 8078)
and
(
  (pocltpsg = '01' and poclcdce = 0)
  or
   pocltpsg = '02'
)
group by poclcdde, poclnpol, poclcdcl
order by min(pocltpsg);
```

Comment: This solution don't remove duplicates. Put the `DISTINCT`, avoid me to use the `ORDER BY´

Comment: Actually, @Thorsten is right.  Because your 2 queries filter on `pcltpsg` but expect different values, duplicates are not even possible to begin with.

Comment: I have updated my query to show how to deal with duplicates.