# php query to sort result from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is possible to make query to get first 3 comments ORDER BY rating, and rest of comments by timestamp?

Im using simple query to get comments on my script, and i sort it by timestamp, here is example

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE content = '$id' AND approved='1' AND parent_id ='0' ORDER BY timestamp DESC");
```

by default all comments have 0 rating in database

Comment: Have you tried `ORDER BY rating DESC LIMIT 3` and then taking the ids of those and throwing them into `WHERE id NOT IN (1, 2, 3) ORDER BY timestamp DESC` ? You would have to have two separate queries, but since you're doing this in PHP, that should be simple.

Comment: for this i need to call two query in database? any chance to make in in one line ?

Comment: You can if you build a stored routine and call it through PHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query below returns the top 3 rated comments as the first 3 rows, and the most recent comments excluding the top 3 for the rest.

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM 
(
    SELECT t2.* FROM (
      SELECT c.* , my_order 1 FROM comments c
      WHERE content = '$id'
          AND approved = '1' 
          AND parent_id = '0'
      ORDER BY rating DESC LIMIT 3
    ) t2
    UNION
    SELECT c.* , my_order 2 FROM comments c
    WHERE content = '$id' 
        AND approved = '1' 
        AND parent_id = '0' 
        AND id NOT IN (
            SELECT id FROM comments
            WHERE content = '$id'
              AND approved = '1' 
              AND parent_id = '0'
            ORDER BY rating DESC LIMIT 3
        )
) t1
ORDER BY 
    my_order, 
    (CASE WHEN my_order = 1 THEN rating ELSE timestamp END)
```

Comment: This is beautiful SQL. I love it.

Comment: Why do you use subqueries?

Comment: @DanFromGermany to order the results of `UNION`. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421049/sql-server-union-what-is-the-default-order-by-behaviour

Comment: @FuzzyTree ah.. I forgot about that limitation