# MS access SQL select two fields and ordered by both fields at the same time

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am using Access to deal with a table with two fields. The table looks like

```
Field1   Field2
  bob      john
  kate     jum
  tim      kim
```

I want to select both fields and output them in order, but I can't use

```
Select Field1,Field2
From table1
order by Field1,Field2;
```

Because I want to sort them by the result of concatenation of Field1 and Filed2, but not order by Field1 first then Field2 secondly. What to do please? thanks.

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense; you order by one column, then a second column.  Are you trying to select Field1 and Field2 as a single column?  Show your expected output results.

Comment: Do you want to sort by result of concatenation of Field1 and Filed2?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes, I want to sort the result of concatenation of both fields.

Comment: As Barry suggest, problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Field1 FROM table1
UNION
SELECT Field2 FROM table1
```

use UNION ALL if you want to keep duplicate names

Comment: Assuming that's their intent, you're not sorting the results

Comment: Are you sure about that?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/421049/sql-server-union-what-is-the-default-order-by-behaviour

Comment: When you do this for one field, it will be sorted as expected. [Check this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_union). With multiple fields I do not have a clue :).

Comment: SO disagrees:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15766359/does-union-all-guarantee-the-order-of-the-result-set

Comment: I can only speak from experience. Never had a problem (Oracle, SQL Server, MySql and Access). But there is a first time for everything. But I think he wants to display the two fields, both ordered. By chance they are already sorted in his example. I expect that is his expected output.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. It works. Using union automatically sort the fields.

Answer (score 0):

I would add an autonumbered field to the table.  Then you can order by that field.