# Display tables data one after one in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

actually I have two tables ,i.e table 1 and table 2 . I need to display data from both tables . if I use

```
SELECT * FROM table 1 UNION SELECT * FROM table 2
```

Now I am getting data randomly from both tables

BUT I need first display table1 data after display table2 data

Comment: Please edit clarifications into your question, not comments. But it is not clear what you are trying to say in your comments--please write longer sentences. Please read & act on [mcve]. PS You must add a column for the table to each, union all, order by that column in the second select (which applies to the union), and select the original columns. Also this is surely a faq, please google many clear, concise, specific statements of you question & read many hits before posting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server UNION - What is the default ORDER BY Behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421049/sql-server-union-what-is-the-default-order-by-behaviour)

Answer (score 1):

In practice, this will do what you want (assuming the tables have the same columns):

```
SELECT * FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table2;
```

It is actually safer to use an explicit `order by`:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM (SELECT t1.*, 1 as which FROM table1 t1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT t2.*, 2 as which FROM table2 t2
     ) t
ORDER BY which;
```

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ANSI requirement that `UNION ALL` return values from the first subquery before the second.  In practice that works in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

One way could be adding a column in the both queries which would indicate the source from where it came.

```
SELECT 
*
FROM 
(
   SELECT *,'T1' AS source FROM table1 
    UNION 
   SELECT *,'T2' FROM table2
) AS t 
ORDER BY t.source ASC;
```

---

[**See Demo**](http://rextester.com/live/DVK51315)

Comment: Select job_id,company_name,job_description,job_location, job_title,maxAnnual_ctc,max_exp_required,minAnnual_ctc,min_exp_required,mandatory_skill1,mandatory_skill2,mandatory_skill3,TQT,suggest_tqt1,suggest_tqt2,suggest_tqt3,Null as jobpost_url,Null as source,added_date from jobs_posted

Comment: UNION Select job_id, company_name,job_description,job_location,job_title,Null as maxAnnual_ctc, Null as max_exp_required,Null as minAnnual_ctc,Null as min_exp_required,mandatory_skill1,Null as mandatory_skill2,Null as mandatory_skill3,Null as TQT,Null as suggest_tqt1,Null as suggest_tqt2,Null as suggest_tqt3,jobpost_url,source,creted_data_time as added_date FROM indeed_jobcrawl ORDER BY added_date desc LIMIT 10

Comment: ADDED ABOVE TWO QUERYS IN A SINGLE QUERY

Comment: In First query table is jobs_posted i have added_date  column , based on that date display data