# "SELECT * FROM view_table WHERE cause" => But the result always reorder

Tags: mysql

In `SELECT * FROM view_table` The result always is

```
-----------------------
|| id  ||   author   ||
-----------------------
||  1  ||    a       || <--
||  1  ||    c       || <--
||  1  ||    b       || <--
||  2  ||    d       ||
||  3  ||    e       ||
```

But when `SELECT * FROM view_table WHERE id=1` the result is

```
-----------------------
|| id  ||   author   ||
-----------------------
||  1  ||    a       ||
||  1  ||    b       ||
||  1  ||    c       ||
```

Or

```
-----------------------
|| id  ||   author   ||
-----------------------
||  1  ||    b       ||
||  1  ||    c       ||
||  1  ||    a       ||
```

Or

```
-----------------------
|| id  ||   author   ||
-----------------------
||  1  ||    a       ||
||  1  ||    c       ||
||  1  ||    b       ||
```

Or

`..`

I want to `SELECT * FROM view_table WHERE id=1` and get the results in the same order as `SELECT * FROM view_table`. How to solve it

Thank You.

Comment: Simply you can't , as long as you do not ask for a precise order (via order by), you can't expect the same order across different select queries

Comment: Have a read through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49815703/what-is-the-default-order-by-for-a-mysql-innodb-query-that-omits-the-order-by

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of results is never guaranteed unless you use an `ORDER BY` clause. How you want to order it, is up to you.

For example,

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM view_table 
WHERE id = 1
ORDER BY author
```

This will sort it based on the author's name (from A to Z, or Z to A if you use `ORDER BY author DESC`).

Alternatively you can add a `Created` column and then order by that column instead, which holds the timestamp when it was created. That could mimic an order that you want to keep.

Comment: Thanks sir. but Can i add timestamp in view table?

Comment: You can add it directly to your table. Make it default `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. That way, you will see when the row was created. Order your result by that.

Answer (score 1):

You want to get the ordered values? It is easy just as below:

```
select * from view_table order by id,author
select * from view_table where id = 1 order by author
```

Comment: I want to get result order like select * from view_table

Comment: When you execute "select * from view_table", the order is also random in fact, so you just need to use the order by clause to make the order fixed.

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is a function of the fact that rows in a table have *no* implied order. If you want your results ordered in a particular way, you must describe that in the query. So for your first query, you would order by `id` and `author`, and for the second, order by `author`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM view_table
ORDER BY id, author
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT *
FROM view_table
WHERE id = 1
ORDER BY author
```

Answer (score 0):

research on `order by`

```
SELECT * FROM view_table WHERE id=1 order by author DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorting based on the author's name

FROM A To Z

```
SELECT * FROM view_table WHERE id = 1 ORDER BY author ASC
```

FROM Z to A

```
SELECT * FROM view_table WHERE id = 1 ORDER BY author DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to order data alphabitic order the you want use SELECT * FROM view_table WHERE id=1 order by author

When you run code each time you get different result. Because of in you table you dont use clustered index. Also if you use pramery key it is also create clustered index on you table. And than you get the same result every time otherwise not. Because without clustered index database doesnt save any order.

Note: you can only use one   clustered index  in a table. But you can use nonclustered index about 999 times.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking into the `ORDER BY` SQL clause.

Using ORDER BY you can do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM view_table WHERE id=1 ORDER BY author
```

You can also use the ASC and DESC to sort the columns further.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

For ascending order with limit

```
SELECT * FROM view_table WHERE id=1 ORDER BY author ASC [LIMIT 3]
```

or

For descending order with limit

```
SELECT * FROM view_table WHERE id=1 ORDER BY author DESC [LIMIT 3]
```